# Не создается файл с логами в папке tomcat/logs

Tags: java, tomcat, логирование, log4j

Не создается файл с логами в папке tomcat/logs, мб что-то не так делаю, подскажите плз.

```
  # Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, FILE

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} %t - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} %t - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.file = ${catalina.base}/logs/exchange_courier.log
log4j.appender.FILE.append = true
log4j.appender.FILE.encoding = UTF-8
# Roll-over the log once per day
#log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

Изменил `log4j.appender.FILE.file = ${catalina.base}/logs/exchange_courier.log`
На `log4j.appender.FILE.file = ${catalina.home}/logs/exchange_courier.log`
и всё заработало)